# Fluent nHibernate - Mapping Many-Many with Composite Key

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm developing an application that has a table structure as follows:
(* denotes key)

**Product:**
*ProductID
*Brand
ProductName

**Categories**
*CategoryID
CategoryName

**ProductCategories**
*CategoryID
*ProductID

Product has a composite ID of ProductID & Brand

Classes are as follows:

```
public class Product
{
  public int ProductID { get; set; }
  public string Brand{ get; set; }
  public string ProductName { get; set; }

  public IEnumerable<Category> { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
  public int CategoryID { get; set; }
  public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

In my mapping for Product, I have

```
  HasManyToMany(x => x.Categories).Table("ProductCategories")
    .ParentKeyColumn(NameOf<Product>.Property(p => p.ProductID))
    .ChildKeyColumn(NameOf<Category>.Property(p => p.CategoryID))
    .Cascade.All();
```

So, basically, I'm trying to have the Categories selected based on the ProductID in ProductCategories table...
Is that possible?

However-
I'm getting an error like:

> must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (Product [ProductID, Brand])

Comment: Just to check I assume you meant ProductCategories when you wrote ItemCategories above?

Answer (score 1):

If **Product** has a composite ID of ProductID & Brand then In **ProductCategories** table must be Composite key of ProductID, Brand and  CategoryID. Otherwise u will get a error:

And mapping Should be like-

```
HasManyToMany<Category>(x => x.Categories)
    .Table("ProductCategories") 
    .ParentKeyColumns.Add("product_id","Brand") 
    .ChildKeyColumn("category_id")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok well in that case you should use this:

```
HasManyToMany<Category>(x => x.Categories)
    .Table("ProductCategories") 
    .ParentKeyColumn("ProductID") 
    .ChildKeyColumn("CategoryID")
```

Comment: I get this exact error: {"Foreign key (FKCDD3036FAD8EF816:ProductCategories [ProductID])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (Product [ProductID, Brand])"}

Comment: Have you tried adding the column Brand to the ProductCategories table to accomodate the composite Id?

Comment: yes, i've just added the brand column to ProductCategories - still same problem

Comment: When you get the message "must have same number of columns" that means that you mapped one column twice or more. Remove the rest of your mapping and leave only the m:n and it should work.

Comment: i have... that's all that's in the mapping... still same problem

Comment: Then is other mapping to the same column. You have 4 columns for example and 5 values. Check your mappings.

Comment: i assure you, that's all i have in the mapping!

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a test and share pls?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6762/discussion-between-mynkow-and-alexjamesbrown)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct. The problem is that .ParentKeyColumn(...) and .ChildKeyColumn(...) expects Db column name. Check if the string NameOf.Property(p => p.ProductID) corresponds to your column name. Also try Specifying explicitly the Type of the categories.

```
HasManyToMany<Category>(x => x.Categories)
    .Table("ProductCategories") //  DB table name
    .ParentKeyColumn("product_id") // column name
    .ChildKeyColumn("category_id") // column name
```

Hope this is the problem. I am using exactly the same mapping in my code.